# My "Bio". Is the language OK?

Tags: word-choice, biography

I have a personal website and I have an "about me" text. I though I'd post it here for professionals to tell me if it's OK (English is not my primary language).

> My name is Primož Kralj, I am 22 years old and I am enrolled in 3rd
>   year of Computer Science and Informatic Technology programme at FERI,
>   University of Maribor. I started to explore computers since I got my
>   first one at age 10. I wrote my first "Hello world" program at age 12
>   in Delphi programming language (without using internet back then :))
>   and made several (mostly personal) websites. **My enthusiasm for
>   emerging technologies haven't smallen since then not even for a bit.** I
>   look-out for any opportunity to participate in summer schools, online
>   classes or any other activities that could benefit my know-how.

I am especially curious about the sentence in bold.

Comment: Welcome.  I realize this was migrated from English, but unfortunately our guidelines do not allow critiques of a piece's grammar.

Comment: @Primož - You may want to look at [our critique guidelines](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work). If this question can be rewritten to meet most of these criteria, we'll consider re-opening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use "lessened" for "smallen" here, and add a comma after "since then", to make it clearer. Also, switch "haven't" for "hasn't".

> My enthusiasm for emerging technologies hasn't lessened since then, not even for a bit.

Also, in the sentence after that, "look-out" is grammatically correct but feels a bit weird there, but I'm not sure I can put my finger on the reason. I would change it to:

> I **am always on the look-out** for any opportunity to participate in summer schools, online classes or any other activities that could benefit my know-how.

Also, in your second sentence, you use "I *started* to explore [..] *since* I got [..]". This is wrong. Either "I *have been exploring* [...] *since*" or "I *started* to explore [...] *when* I got". *to start* is a one-off action that happened at a specific time, not something that has been happening since.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough review. I have edited the text like you proposed.

Answer (score 2):

*Enthusiasm* is singular.

*Small* is an adjective not a verb.

So "My enthusiasm for emerging technologies has not reduced at all since then" would be better.

Comment: I agree with you and indeed it sounds better.
I have found [smallen](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smallen) to be verb too though.

Comment: *Smallen* is too obscure to appear in the abridged Merriam Webster. Don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Enthusiasm may "**fade**" or "**wane**". These are the usual collocations for "enthusiasm".

> Wane: To decrease gradually in size, amount, intensity, or degree; decline.

So,

> My enthusiasm ... **has** never waned...

would be better.

Also, you may use **decrease**